# Using boto for S3 upload I'm getting a EOF error

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto

I'm trying to upload a file to S3 (actually the upload works) but my app crashes and throws the error saying:

`fp is at EOF. Use rewind option or seek() to data start.`

I saw that some ways people have solved the problem was adding `rewind=True` to their set_contents_from_string call. However this throws the following error:

`set_contents_from_string() got an unexpected keyword argument 'rewind'`

The following is the content of my `views.py`. What am I doing wrong?

```
def store_in_s3(filename, filecontent):
    conn = S3Connection(settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
    b = conn.create_bucket('mybucket')
    mime = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)[0]
    k = Key(b)
    k.key = filename
    k.set_metadata("Content-Type", mime)
    k.set_contents_from_string(filecontent)
    #k.set_contents_from_string(filecontent, rewind=True)
    k.set_acl("public-read")

def add_m(request, points=None):
    mname = request.GET.get ('mname')
    format = request.GET.get ('format')
    type = request.GET.get ('type')
    if request.method == "POST":
        formtoaddm = spiceform(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formtoaddm.is_valid():
            new_m = formtoaddm.save(commit=False)
            new_m.adder = request.user
            mname = new_m.mname
            file = request.FILES['content']
            filename = file.name
            filecontent = file.read()
            store_in_s3(filename, filecontent)
            ...
```

Comment: Ok I think I fixed it by adding: 

`file.seek(0)` after reading it. But I'm not sure why. Could someone explain?

Comment: file.seek(0) puts the read cursor back at the beginning of the file so you can then do a file.read() again and fetch all the contents again.

Comment: Have you tried with this line uncommented: #k.set_contents_from_string(filecontent, rewind=True) ?

Answer (score 2):

after

```
filecontent = file.read()
```

Put:

```
file.seek(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

See the final comment [here](https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/883). Presuming that you're using Django-Storages, just upgrade to the latest version, should fix the issue.